# longest line in vim?

Tags: vim, command

Is there a command to determine length of a longest line in vim? And to append that length at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Must this be done in Vim?  I ask because this is a quite specific thing to want to do, and it would probably be quicker to put together a Python/Perl/Ruby script to do it if you need it done on multiple files.

Comment: This sounds like your asking for the wrong solution to the actual problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ZoogieZork: sometimes vim is enough, and simple enough as well, there is no need to use external tools.

Answer (score 21):

Gnu's wc command has a -L --max-line-length option which prints out the max line length of the file. See the [gnu man wc](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wc). The freebsd wc also has -L, but not --max-line-length, see [freebsd man wc](http://fuse4bsd.creo.hu/localcgi/man-cgi.cgi?wc+1).

How to use these from vim? The command:

```
:%!wc -L
```

Will filter the open file through wc -L and make the file's contents the maximum line length.

To retain the file contents and put the maximum line length on the first line do:

```
:%yank
:%!wc -L
:put
```

Instead of using wc, [Find length of longest line - awk bash](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/04/find-length-of-longest-line-awk-bash.html) describes how to use awk to find the length of the longest line.

Ok, now for a pure Vim solution. I'm somewhat new to scripting, but here goes. What follows is based on the FilterLongestLineLength function from [textfilter](http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/).

```
function! PrependLongestLineLength ( )
  let maxlength   = 0
  let linenumber  = 1
  while linenumber <= line("$")
    exe ":".linenumber
    let linelength  = virtcol("$")
    if maxlength < linelength
      let maxlength = linelength
    endif
    let linenumber  = linenumber+1
  endwhile

  exe ':0'
  exe 'normal O'
  exe 'normal 0C'.maxlength
endfunction

command PrependLongestLineLength call PrependLongestLineLength()
```

Put this code in a .vim file (or your .vimrc) and :source the file. Then use the new command:

```
:PrependLongestLineLength
```

Thanks, figuring this out was fun.

Comment: I was on something like !awk '{print(length($0))}' < yourfile | sort | tail -1
lol

Comment: Even if Jonathan (pre-vim-7) solution is a bit complex, he is right in using `virtcol()`, tabulations shall not be counted as '1'. I'm afraid all other solutions based on wc, awk, perl, etc won't give correct answers.

Answer (score 8):

If you work with tabulations expanded, a simple

```
:0put=max(map(getline(1,'$'), 'len(v:val)'))
```

is enough.

Otherwise, I guess we will need the following (that you could find as the last example in `:h virtcol()`, minus the -1):

```
0put=max(map(range(1, line('$')), "virtcol([v:val, '$'])-1"))
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that line "simple". It works though, so no complaints.

Answer (score 2):

`:!wc -L %`
rather than
`:%!wc -L`

To append that length at the beginning of the file:
`:0r !wc -L % | cut -d' ' -f1`

Comment: The advantage of `%!wc -L` is that it works on unsaved or unnamed buffers.

Comment: Note that it may cause some problems if there are spaces or some special characters in file name. Use `"%"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple, hence easily-remembered approach:

- select all text: `ggVG`
- substitute each character (.) with "a": `:'<,'>s/./a/g`
- sort, unique: `:'<,'>sort u`
- count the characters in the longest line (if too many characters to easily count, just look at the column position in the Vim status bar)

I applied this to examine Enzyme Commission (EC) numbers, prior to making a PostgreSQL table:

I copied the ec_numbers data to Calc, then took each column in Neovim, replaced each character with "a",

```
:'<,'>s/./a/g
```

and then sorted for unique lines

```
:'<,'>sort u

aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
```

... so the longest EC number entry [x.x.x.x] is 11 char, VARCHAR(11).

Similarly applied to the Accepted Names, we get

```
aaaaa
aaaaaa
...
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

i.e. the longest name is 147 char: VARCHAR(200) should cover it!

[image: line_length_count]

Answer (score 1):

For neovim users:

```lua
local lines = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_lines(bufnr, 0, -1, false)

local width = #(lines[1])

for _, line in ipairs(lines) do
  if #line > width then
    width = #line
  end
end
```