# How to use vim/tabularize to center lines but leave prefix?

Tags: vim, alignment

I recently had the idea to try to use tabularize to "center" some lines. For example, here are some Vim plugins:

```
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
```

If I run `:Tabularize /\//r0c0l0`, what I get is:

```
  Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
 Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'
   Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
      Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
```

This is pretty close, except `Plug` is also moved. Is there a way to use tabularize to center based on the slash but leave the `Plug` unmoved on the left, like the following:

```
Plug  'ervandew/supertab'
Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plug   'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug      'kien/ctrlp.vim'
```

Comment: Did you tried with visual block mode?

Comment: @rityzmon, mind accepting one the answers?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to search for the left part of the package specification and align by that, like:

```
:Tabularize /'[^/]\+/l1r0l0
```

So the left side will be the `Plug`, the middle is the `'<package author>`, and the right part is the `\<package name>'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do actually that with another approach and which will be in two steps:

```
:let temp=&textwidth | :%s:/:/\r:g | execute "set textwidth=".max(map(getline(1,'$'),'len(v:val)')) | :%right | :%normal! Jx
:execute "set textwidth=".temp | %s/^\(.*\)\(Plug\)\(.\+\)'/\2\1\3'/g
```

---

[max(map(getline(1,'$'),'len(v:val)'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075276/longest-line-in-vim)

Comment: I just do it for fun ! :) I like to push myself !

Comment: Anything you can do with a plugin, you can also do without.  At worst, you'd just have to type the body of the plugin to do it. :) The question is, which approach is more __efficient__?