# How to get the number of column in the longest line with vim command?

Tags: vim

In a file edited in vim,how to get the number of character in the  longest line with vim command?
And the line number?

Comment: The simplest way of getting the length of the longest line would be to give the problem to your shell instead: `:!wc -L < %`

Comment: Which line is it?

Comment: do you want to get the length of certain line or you want to first find the longest line and then get the length?

Comment: Two problems 1. get the column number of the longest line

Comment: `:!wc -L < % ` do it for me.

Comment: 2. Which line is the longest line,the line number of longest line.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some Unix tools like `wc` and `awk` is probably easier and shorter (and other answers / comments seem to go for them), so here is a pure Vimscript solution:

```
let widths = map(getline(1, '$'), 'strdisplaywidth(v:val)')
let maxWidth = max(widths)
let longestLines = filter(map(copy(widths), 'v:val == maxWidth ? (v:key + 1) : ""'), '! empty(v:val)')
echo printf('max width is %d, found in line(s) %s', maxWidth, join(longestLines, ', '))
```

It converts all lines into a List of their lengths, then finds the maximum value. All List entries with that value are then filtered and translated into their line numbers (= List index + 1). Finally, the result is printed.

Answer (score 2):

This will print the line number, the length and the line:

```
:%!awk ' { if ( length > L ) { L=length ;s=$0 } }END{ print NR, L, "\""s"\"" }'
```

http://www.unixcl.com/2009/04/find-length-of-longest-line-awk-bash.html

Comment: 1) this will clear the whole buffer with the column number. 2) if we used external cmd, the `wc -L` (see the comment under the question) is much simpler than your awk. 3), you awk could be improved by `awk '{m=length>m?length:m}END{print m}'`

Comment: 1)yup, but you can use something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/2075372/94746 2) `wc -L` is simpler, but it doesn't return the line number. 3) it doesn't print the line number